# qrcode_detection problem

Tags: ros, kinect, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone

I want to use hector_qrcode_detection package. But i dont know if an uvc cemera is enough. In the launch file i see three different vision sources:

> ```
> <launch>
> ```

```
<remap from="image_percept" to="worldmodel/image_percept" />
```

> ```
> <node name="qrcode_detection_kinect" pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" args="load hector_qrcode_detection/qrcode_detection openni/openni_nodelet_manager">
> <remap from="openni/image"             to="/image_raw" />
> <remap from="openni/image_percept"     to="worldmodel/image_percept" />
> <remap from="openni/image/qrcode"      to="image/qrcode" />
> <remap from="openni/image/camera_info" to="image/camera_info" />
> ```

```
</node>
```

> ```
> <node name="qrcode_detection_pseye_left" pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" args="load hector_qrcode_detection/qrcode_detection pseye_camera_left">
> <remap from="image" to="left/image_mono" />
> ```

```
</node>
```

> ```
> <node name="qrcode_detection_pseye_right" pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" args="load hector_qrcode_detection/qrcode_detection pseye_camera_right">
> <remap from="image" to="right/image_mono" />
> ```

```
</node>
```

> ```
> </launch>
> ```

Do i need to add kinect and another camera to use it? Honestly i can not do it with my uvc camera.

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206177/qrcode_detection-problem/) by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2015-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You do not need another camera. The above launch files loads a separate instance of the qrcode detection nodelet into each camera's nodelet manager (kinect, and two pseye cameras).

If you're looking to do some very simple qr code detection, you can also try [zbar_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/zbar_ros), sample launchfile [here](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/zbar_ros/blob/hydro-devel/launch/example.launch).

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on 2015-03-30**:
Thanks for your help. It seems useful package. But when i try to run launch file i see an error: Skipping XML Document "/opt/ros/hydro/share/zbar_ros/nodelets.xml". Do you know how should i add nodelets,xml file to my package?

**Comment by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on 2015-03-30**:
I solved it. Simplely i copied nodelets.xml from your repository to my zbar_ros directory.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2015-03-31**:
Thanks for letting me know, fixed here https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/zbar_ros/commit/1db9b654530a700bbcf0941fa632df1737eeb176

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-05-16**:
But when I try to use `zbar_ros` with a usbCamera . I see some errors.
`[FATAL] [1431789473.318155604]: Service call failed!`

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-05-16**:
[zbar_manager-1] process has died [pid 2691, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=zbar_manager __log:=/home/exbot/.ros/log/83a7a9c2-fbdb-11e4-9ba8-485ab6072ea3/zbar_manager-1.log].
log file: /home/exbot/.ros/log/83a7a9c2-fbdb-11e4-9ba8-485ab6072ea3/zbar_manager-1.

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-05-16**:
[uvc_camera-2] process has died [pid 2692, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load uvc_camera/CameraNodelet zbar_manager image_raw:=image __name:=uvc_camera __log:=/home/exbot/.ros/log/83a7a9c2-fbdb-11e4-9ba8-485ab6072ea3/uvc_camera-2.log].

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2015-05-25**:
Please make a separate issue and post more information.

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-05-28**:
Well, I has solved this problem. If I want to use zbar_ros to identify QR code, I just need to change the topic's name. In fact , I don't have a nodelet for usb_cam so that I occured such problems.